# Files migration from local dev site

Tags: files, migrations, 9

I'm migrating from Drupal 7 to Drupal 9 and am having an issue with my source files getting found with the upgrade_d7_file migration. My public files directory for my source site is **not** 'sites/default/files'. It's a multisite instance and it's public file directory is 'sites/example.com/files'. I have exported the configuration generated with migrate-upgrade --configure-only and can change the source_base_path value, then import it and see changes, but 'sites/default/files' gets added to the end of whatever I put into the source_base_path value. I do have my public files system path defined in 'admin/config/media/file-system' of the source site.

Is there a place to set the default path to start with something other than *sites/default/files* for the source site?

Added edit

I added $conf['file_public_path'] = 'sites/example.com/files'; to my settings.php file, but it was still not used. I then edited the exported migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_file.yml file, but not the source_base_path. I added another constant underneath it "file_public_path: sites/example.com/files" then in the process section edited source_full_path's concat plugin section to

```
source_full_path:
  -
    plugin: concat
    delimiter: /
    source:
      - constants/source_base_path
      - constants/file_public_path
      - filename
  -
```

Then reimported the config. This worked, but it seems like a ridiculous workaround.

Thanks